# Creating a Vector of Values With Common Traits

Tags: r

I am trying to create a vector of character data in the form "yyyymm".

The following code gives me the desired results, but necessitates a lot of manual typing if I was to look at a larger time frame.

```
for(i in 2000:2010){
yyyy.mm=format(seq(i+.01, 1+.12, by=.01), digits=6)
yyyymm=sub("[.]","",yyyy.mm)
name=paste0("Y",i)
assign(name, yyyymm)
}

date=as.character(c(Y2000, Y2001, etc.))
```

Is there be a way to append characters to each element of a vector systematical? Like I have a vector in the form

```
y=c("2000","2001",...)
```

Another in the form

```
m=c("01", "02",...)
```

And I add every element in m to the end of each element in y? Any other suggestions with how to approach this would be appreciated.

Comment: Try with `c(outer(y, m, FUN = paste0))` or `paste0(rep(y, length(m)), rep(m, length(y)))`

Comment: Seems like you want to work with dates. There are date-specifc functions that can help with that. For example `format(seq.Date(as.Date("2000-01-1"), as.Date("2012-12-1"), by="month"), "%Y%m")`

Comment: Ah, did not think to use the number of months for the repetition. This works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the two vectors then you can use `expand.grid`

For example

```
years <- seq(2000, 2012, 1)
months <- seq(1, 12, 1)

ymo <- expand.grid(years, months)
key <- paste0(ymo$Var1, ymo$Var2)
```

However, if you want the format to of the sequence to have a preceding zero for the single digit months ("201201" vs "20121") you would have to further process the month vector before expanding.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"),as.Date("2010-12-31"),1)
```

Comment: Close, but no. The output must be strictly "yyyymm", and substituting the days at the end would be tough

Comment: Try to provide runnable example to make it easy to understand what you wand. You can always cut off days from dates and find unique months.Loops are slow and ugly anyway

Comment: building on this answer is this what you are after:
x <- gsub("-","",seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"),as.Date("2010-12-31"),1));
substr(x, 1,6)

Comment: @user1658170 "MrFlick" had a comment in the original post that probably is best for using "seq(as.Date(..."